# Printers keep reappearing despite printer GPP being deleted

Tags: windows-8, printer

Seem to be stuck with a couple of printers which keeps reappearing.  I can delete them from device manager but as soon as I scan for new hardware they reappear again.

This printer was came originally from a printer GPP.

- Printer GPP has now been deleted
- Windows 8 workstation has been removed from the domain
- Printer driver and queue from the server have been deleted

Yet still the printers keep reappearing.

Any suggestions where these are coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you remove a Group Policy (or set it back to "Not Configured"), doesn't mean that it gets un-set on the client.  The settings (stored in the registry) still remain, unless configured to be something else.

Search your registry for the printer (by share name probably), and remove the entries manually.

Off the top of my head, a few specific keys to check:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Connections`

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connection`

and

`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Printers`

Comment: Thanks techie007, you got it.  The first two keys I knew about but have never had reason to encounter .Default\Printers before.  Deleted from there and now finally printers have gone away.  Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I think if you apply the printer GPPs at the Computer level, they get put in the Default user section.